# Passing AWS credentials to Python container

Tags: python, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am building Python container for the first time using VS Code and WSL2. Here is my sample Python code. It runs fine in VS interactive mode because it is picking up my default AWS credentials.

```
import boto3
s3BucketName = 'test-log-files'
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def s3move():
    try:
        s3.Object(s3BucketName, "destination/Changes.xlsx").copy_from(CopySource=(s3BucketName + "/source/Changes.xlsx"))
        s3.Object(s3BucketName,"source/Changes.xlsx").delete()
        print("Transfer Complete")
    except:
        print("Transfer failed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s3move()
```

The Dockerfile built by VS Code:

```
# For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Install pip requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install boto3

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

# Switching to a non-root user, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-user-rights
RUN useradd appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD ["python", "S3MoveFiles/S3MoveFiles.py"]
```

I would like to test this using docker container and seems like I have to pass the AWS credentials to the container. While there are other ways and probably more secure ways, I wanted to test the method by mounting the volume in a docker command as an argument.

```
docker run -v ~/.aws/credentials:/appuser/home/.aws/credentials:ro image_id
```

I get the "Transfer failed" message in the Terminal window in VS Code. What am I doing wrong here? Checked several articles but couldn't find any hints. I am not logged in as root.

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve]. In particular, people shouldn't have to guess where and when that "transfer failed" message occurs. As a new user, please also take the [tour] and read [ask]. BTW: Check the user inside the container, it may not have the same home directory as you expect.

Comment: I am trying to do the same. Did you find a solution?